# Anydesk error: Aborted (core dumped) in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: anydesk

I have recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my computer.

Initially I installed libgtkglext1 using following command.

```
sudo apt-get install libgtkglext1
```

After that I installed libpangox-1.0-0 using following command.

```
wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/pangox-compat/libpangox-1.0-0_0.0.2-5.1_amd64.deb

sudo apt install ./libpangox-1.0-0_0.0.2-5.1_amd64.deb
```

Now when I run **./anydesk** on my terminal I get the following error:

```
Aborted (core dumped)
```

How to fix it? Please help.

Comment: You can't mix debian packages with Ubuntu packages, since they are compiled against other libraries (or versions of them). Though Ubuntu derives from debian, they are not compatible (Check Linus Torvalds ranting about Linux desktops)

Comment: If I remove libpangox package then I get this error:

./anydesk: error while loading shared libraries: libpangox-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: After removing the debian libpangoxft I run the following command: sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoxft-1.0.so.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangox-1.0.so.0

Again "Aborted (core dumped)" error occured

Comment: I have the same problem. But anydesk_5.5.6-1_amd64.deb version is working -> https://download.anydesk.com/linux/

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem in this way.

I downloaded / installed the following version of libpangox:
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pangox-compat/libpangox-1.0-0_0.0.2-5.1_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i libpangox-1.0-0_0.0.2-5.1_amd64.deb

I downloaded / installed the following version of Anydesk:
wget https://anydesk.com/de/downloads/thank-you?dv=deb_64

sudo dpkg -i anydesk_6.1.1-1_amd64.deb

When I tried to start Anydesk it gave me:
Aborted (core dumped)

From the shell I went to the / home / user folder and deleted the .anydesk directory

Now works :)